# How do I use Lua hooks to find out the name of the currently running function?

Tags: c, lua, debugging

I am currently running a Lua script with a hook attached using `LUA_MASKCALL` and the hook function implemented as follows:

```
void LuaHook(lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar) {
    switch(ar->event) {
        case LUA_HOOKCALL:
            lua_getinfo(L, ">n", ar);
            //breakpoint here...
        } break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

I would like to get the name of the called function, but am not sure I am doing it correctly since it never seems to give me anything (the breakpoint is hit at the appropriate times though). The functions that are called are bound C functions that do have names so that seems weird. Overall `lua_getinfo` is a complete mystery to me and the documentation does not clear things up either so any help would be greatly appreciated on this one.

Comment: Dunno, but in the Lua Reference, they call lua_getinfo(L, ">n", &ar), the ampersand is missing in your code, or am I wrong?

Comment: They do so because they have defined ar to be 'lua_Debug ar;' (not a pointer). It would not have compiled if I had done such an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lua_getstack` did the trick so never mind